# How to cut off persp3d outside of the plot area

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting the bivariate function x*y using persp3d.

If I do not use zlim the shape of the graph is greatly distorted by rescaling:

```
persp3D(x,y,z, theta = 10, phi = 15, forceClipregion = TRUE, shade = 0.3)
```

[image: without zlim]

If I do use zlim the function plots outside of the plot area, and most of the coloring is invisible:

```
persp3D(x,y,z, theta = 10, phi = 15, zlim=c(0,4), forceClipregion = TRUE, shade = 0.3)
```

[image]

Is there a way to make R crop the plot at the top of the box?

Comment: Did you try `zlim=c(0,15)`?

Comment: @G5W Yes. zlim=c(0,16) results in the first image, zlim=c(0,15) results in a similar image with the graph portruding slightly.